# How to do exercise with past body injury?

Tags: exercise, workout

I dislocated my shoulder a year ago. It has completely healed and right now I do not feel any pain there. But i am kind of afraid to do any workout such as push up, pull-ups and weightlifting. But I am keen on doing exercise and want to develop muscle mass. How to go about it?

Comment: First of all, consult with your doctor before staring any workout. Even if you have no pain, there's quite a possibility that the healing hasn't happened 100%. If you are given green signal by your doctor, only then think of any workout. Start slow, go with light weights. Do assisted pull-ups, and always be around an instructor who knows what he's doing. Don't go too extreme, and achieve your goals slowly. All that is fine, but doctor's consultation or that of a therapist is a must.

Comment: I don't think this question is off-topic.  It appears to be about injury prevention which is an allowed topic.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, consult with your doctor, and tell them about your past history of injury, before staring any workout. The doctor who diagnosed you and helped you with the healing would be the best one to suggest anything. Even if you have no pain, there's quite a possibility that the healing hasn't happened 100%. If you are given green signal by your doctor, only then think of any workout.

Start slow, go with light weights. Do assisted pull-ups, and always be around an instructor who knows what he's doing. Doing things right is the key, so just ensure you do everything with the correct form, without stressing yourself too much. Don't go too extreme, and achieve your goals slowly and progressively, in fragments. Eat well and rest properly, to recover. Above all, have patience. You are only going to deal with yourself and not anyone else, so give yourself the time. Results will show up.

All that is fine, but doctor's consultation or that of a therapist is a must, just to ensure you are allowed to workout based on the history of your injury.